# How to show image in Google Sheets Sidebar based on active cell

Tags: html, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to create an "image viewer" in Google Sheets.

When the user runs the sidebar, I want it to show the image link that is contained in whatever cell is active.

There is more logic I want to build in (potentially changing the picture when the active cell changes in a specific column, etc), but for now I'm just stuck surfacing the image.

When I use a static link in the code (the first commented out line), I can see it in the sidebar perfectly.

However, when I try to retrieve the image link from the active cell, the sidebar works but with a broken image link.

Any thoughts? Is my image link possibly set up wrong? Not sure where to go from here - have tried editing it but no luck.

```
//@OnlyCurrentDoc



function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp
   .getUi()
   .createMenu("Admin")
   .addItem("Admin page", "showAdminSidebar")
   .addToUi();
}

function showAdminSidebar() {

var ssThis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeSheet = ssThis.getActiveSheet();
var currentCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell();


////THIS LINK WORKS

//  var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FT-abnEWUAINPuV?format=jpg&name=4096x4096' /></p>");


////USING LINK BASED ON CURRENT CELL: DOESNT SHOW IMAGE

  var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src="+currentCell+" /></p>");
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(image);

 Logger.log(currentCell)
}
```

Sample sheet with image links in cells a10 and a11:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QBukh3yTgbAl1j7-2rgG4Dsxwv2KxkMcIMFl6FnZogU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, `currentCell` of `var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src="+currentCell+" /></p>");` is `var currentCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell();`. In this case, the Class Range object is directly used. If you want to use the URL in the active cell, please modify it as follows.

#### From:

```
var currentCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell();


////THIS LINK WORKS

//  var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src='https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FT-abnEWUAINPuV?format=jpg&name=4096x4096' /></p>");


////USING LINK BASED ON CURRENT CELL: DOESNT SHOW IMAGE

var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src="+currentCell+" /></p>");
```

#### To:

```
var currentCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell().getDisplayValue();
if (!currentCell || !(/^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(currentCell))) return;  
var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src='" + currentCell + "' /></p>");
```

#### Reference:

- [getCurrentCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcurrentcell)

### Added:

When my proposed modification is reflected in your script, `showAdminSidebar()` is modified as follows. So, please replace your current `showAdminSidebar()` as follows, and test it again.

```js
function showAdminSidebar() {
  var ssThis = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ssThis.getActiveSheet();
  var currentCell = activeSheet.getCurrentCell().getDisplayValue();
  if (!currentCell || !(/^https?:\/\/.*$/.test(currentCell))) return;
  var image = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<p><img src='" + currentCell + "' /></p>");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(image);
}
```

Comment: what can't you do!! Amazing -- unfortunately, I'm still getting the image broken logo in my sidebar... I updated the code and am using the links in cell B2 and B3 (they both show an image when I use the Sheets formula IMAGE... is there anything else I need to change?  I know it must be very close to perfect but can't seem to get it working here at the moment

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I noticed that a modification point in the script. So, I updated it. Please confirm it again.

Comment: Hmmm I'm still receiving the same result -- going to try to troubleshoot, actually have to leave my computer for a few hours but will be back online as soon as possible. Thanks for this - it must be a small thing

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed modification using your provided Spreadsheet when a cell "B2" or "B3" is selected and run the script, the image is shown in the sidebar. So, in this case, it is required to know your situation. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Anthony Madle From your reply, I'm worried that you might have miscopied my proposed script. So, I added the modified `showAdminSidebar()` in my answer. Could you please confirm it? When I tested it using your Spreadsheet, I could confirm that the image is shown in the sidebar.

Comment: WOW it is AMAZING!! I think for some reason my sheet was still calling my old script, even though I had deleted it and refreshed.  I made a copy of the sheet, put the script in, and BOOM! amazing answer. So simple and easy.  I'm going to keep building off this, amazing

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying and testing it again. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

Sidebar Image Viewer

GS:

```
function myfunk() {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2").evaluate().setTitle("Image Viewer");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
    }

function getLinkId() {
  return "image file id";//file id of image you shared to public
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=<?=getLinkId()?>" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @Cooper thanks for the help, confused how to run this -- running myfunk but the sidebar isn't showing oddly enough.  Also, is this saying I would need to upload the images to Google Drive, then get all the IDs? What I'm trying to do is have a list of image addresses in a column, and create a tool that will show the image in the sidebar when a link is clicked.  I could upload them to drive and put all Drive links, but a little confused with this.  I label the HTML as ah2? And then how could I reference my image link that is contained in a cell? Apologies for the confusion

Comment: What did you name the html file?

Comment: I named it `ah2.html`

Comment: I thought it needed to be named ah2 based on the html line in the GS - apologies, I';m still learning this

Comment: ah2 is correct.

Comment: Did you put the id of the image file into the getLinkId() function

Comment: And did you share that image file to anyone that has link